# How to redirect back to login page if localstorage access_token is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-router-dom

I have a condition where my localStorage becomes `undefined` in that condition i want user to be redirected to login page but Its not working I tried doing this but I don't what is the issue here.
This is my `PrivateRoute.js` code

> PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import LocalStorageService from "../utilities/LocalStorageService";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    // Show the component only when the user is logged in
    // Otherwise, redirect the user to /signin page
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        LocalStorageService.getAccessToken() &&
        typeof (LocalStorageService.getAccessToken() !== undefined) ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

> LocalStorageService

```
const LocalStorageService = (function () {

  function _getAccessToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("access_token");
}

  return {
   
    getAccessToken: _getAccessToken,
   
  };
})();
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

the below code will return `"boolean"`, it's always `true`

```
typeof (LocalStorageService.getAccessToken() !== undefined)
```

You should delete  the `()` like the below code

```
typeof LocalStorageService.getAccessToken() !== undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do your have to check `typeof (LocalStorageService.getAccessToken() !== undefined)` ? I think this is enough:

```
render={(props) => {
  if (LocalStorageService.getAccessToken()) {
    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
  }
  return (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  );
}}
```

Comment: it is not redirecting to `/login` page